# C# equivalent to boost::gregorian generators

Tags: c#, .net, date

I'm searching for a C# equivalent to the functionality provided by the boost:gregorian generators.

Specifically, I have wildcard dates and need to convert them to concrete dates.
For example a wildcard 'Third Monday in January' could be done with boost::gregorian as

```
typedef nth_day_of_the_week_in_month nth_dow;
nth_dow ndm(nth_dow::third, Monday,Jan);
date d = ndm.get_date(2002);
//2002-Jan-21
```

By using this feature, it can then be further wildcarded as 'Third Monday every month', or '.. every odd month'.

What is the best way to achieve such behaviour in C#?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is "write it" or "find a library which does it". Neither of those two could/should be answered here. (One is too broad, the other is a request for offsite resource)

Comment: My hope was that somewhere within the .net framework such functionality lies hidden. Your comment sounds like that is not the case, in which case I agree that is can not be answered here. Thank you.

Comment: Its fairly trivial to write a method like `GetNthWeekDayInMonth(int yr, int mth, DayOfWeek dow)`, but to support the kind of combinations you describe there is nothing "built in" of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this straight up with DateTime.DaysInMonth foreach loop then check the day, but it can be a pain so I suggest you just set up a method such as below

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDatesInMonth(int year, int month)
{
    int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    for (int day = 1; day <= days; day++)
    {
         yield return new DateTime(year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Then you can do something similar to the below code:

```
foreach (DateTime date in AllDatesInMonth(2016,4).Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday))
    break; //This will work as it will execute the break as soon as it hits the first monday of the month
```

What do you mean by wildcard dates though? TimeSpans?

Comment: For your second bit of code - seeing as were using `IEnumerable<DateTime>` - it may as well just be `AllDatesInMonth(2016,4).Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);`

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, I 'm not 100% confident with Linq yet :-) I'll update as suggested

Comment: Right now I am given wildcards like 'first/second/..../last Monday' or 'odd months/even months'. The goal right now is to find all specific dates matching these wildcards within a specific date period. This might be a single date in case of 'Second Monday in April' when using '2016' as date period. In case of 'Every second week in every odd month in 2016' it would give a collection of specific dates.

Comment: @fleitner Those don't seem like normal wildcards for datetime/timespan. I suggest you either write a custom method for it (Ask if you want a hand), or just clean up whatever is generating those wildcards.

Comment: @Anonymouse The wildcards are specified by user input. I need to collect and store these (in any way I like) and, for specific time ranges (e.g. now+12months), calculate specific dates within that range. I know they are not normal wildcards for the C# datetime object, but I hoped that somewhere hidden deep inside the .net framework there might be a functionality similar to boost::gregorian that can be utilized. Looks like I'm out of luck though :)

Comment: @fleitner I'm afraid not, You can either have DateTime, which is an exact Date and Time, or you can have a TimeSpan, which is a section of time specified by using Subtraction of DateTime types (`DateTime.UTCNow - DateTime.UTCNow.AddYears(-7)`)

Comment: @Anonymouse I feared so. Of course thank you for the explanation, now I know that I have to spend the time required to write this functionality (and can justify that time)